# unable to exit the window with pygame.time.wait()?

Tags: pygame

I am unable to close out the game window after insertion of `pygame.time.wait(1000)` in my main game loop, for example:

```
while True:
    ev = pygame.event.wait()
    if ev.type == pygame.QUIT:
        break
    ...
    pygame.display.update()
    pygame.time.wait(1000)
```

what is the issue here and is there any work around?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is because `1000ms` is `1s` and it is long time for program. At this time program doesn't check `pygame.event` so it can't `break` mainloop (`while True`) and you can't `quit` - better use smaller value  - `100ms` (`0.1s`) or smaller.

If you use `40ms` it gives you `1000ms/40ms = 25 FPS` (`Frames Per Seconds`)

---

You can use `Clock()` to set FPS more precisely

```
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

# mainloop

    clock.tick(25)
```